# I'm getting "Files different from the server" when playing Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

So, I recently start to play my copy of MW2 for PC using Steam.

But every time I try to play Multiplayer I load the map up then and I'm sent back to the lobby with the error `Files different from the server`.

Can someone please help me? What could be causing this error and how could I fix it?

Comment: What are your system configurations ? did you tried update your copy to the current version on Steam?

Answer (score 2):

First, let me just say that sometimes it could be the server that is different from the client, but if this keeps happening there are a few things you could try:

- In Steam, select the game, then `Right Click->Properties`, go to the `Local Files` tab, and click `Verify Integrity of Game Cache`. If steam finds any outdated/missing files, it will inform you and start downloading them.
- Browse to the `steamapps` folder, locate your copy of MW2, and inside `/main`, delete (or cut out) all the `iw_XX.iwd` files. re-run the verify integrity. It should pick up the missing files and re-download them.

Finally, the most drastic:

- `Right Click->Properties`, go to `Local Files`, and `Delete Local Game Content`. Once it is done, go into `steamapps` and make sure there are no remaining files. If there are (shouldn't be), delete them. Then re-download the game.

I got stuck with the last option on MW3, it sucked, but luckily I had the game discs (I bought it retail). I just installed off them and then let steam run updates.

Comment: This worked like a charm, now i can play, thanks man :D

Comment: @Matt - No problem, glad I could help :). Also welcome to the site! If this answers your question, you can mark it as solved so that future visitors know this is what worked for you. Just click the outlined check under the vote count. For more info, feel free to check out the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)